# Can I use scene raycast to identify the object with the largest z value?

Tags: python

I am trying to identify the object that is at the highest location in the z direction, and scene raycast seems like it should give me that information if I put a grid above the objects in my scene and raycast from locations in the grid.  Here is my test script:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=4, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_grid_add(size=5, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.context.object.location[2] = 5

import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

context = bpy.context
vl = context.view_layer
scene = context.scene

ob = context.active_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()

for poly in me.polygons:
   o = poly.center
   d = poly.normal

   hit, loc, norm, idx, obj, mw = scene.ray_cast(vl.depsgraph, o, d)
   print("results ",hit,obj,poly,loc)
```

The problem is that the raycast only finds the plane and not the cube.  I figured out that if I subdivide the cube, then the raycast hits it.  However, I would like to be able to identify the object at the highest z location without subdividing all my objects.  Is there a way to do that or I am using the wrong method?

Comment: I've tried something similar once, but that was using world position data.
Maybe try to find the object with the greater position color

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jqwK.png

Answer (score 0):

Don't iterate over polygons, either check bounding box for simple cases:

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C, data as D

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=4, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_grid_add(size=5, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
C.object.location.z = 5

max_z = lambda ob: max(co[2] for co in ob.bound_box)
obs_with_max_z = ((ob, ob.location.z + max_z(ob)) for ob in D.objects)
top_ob = max(obs_with_max_z, key=lambda x:x[1])

print(f"The highest object is {top_ob[0].name}, reaching as high as {top_ob[1]}")
```

Or iterate over vertex (not polygons) world coordinates:

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C, data as D
from mathutils import Vector

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=4, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_grid_add(size=5, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
C.object.location.z = 5

max_z = lambda ob: max((ob.matrix_world @ Vector(co))[2] for co in ob.bound_box)
obs_with_max_z = ((ob, max_z(ob)) for ob in D.objects)
top_ob = max(obs_with_max_z, key=lambda x:x[1])

print(f"The highest object is {top_ob[0].name}, reaching as high as {top_ob[1]}")
```

You might want to consider transforming the object by the world matrix, `foreach_get` numpy array of coordinates, slicing the Z column, taking the maximum of that and transforming the object back (or transforming a copy etc.).